# Tag tooltip not showing correctly in Opera

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Im using Opera Version 12.14 Build 1738; my OS is Windows 7

The tooltip for tags appears to be broken.

[image]

Comment: Is this why they're going to WebKit? :)

Comment: No repro, exactly the same version: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QgDzU.png

Comment: @NickCraver Should it be tagged as solved now?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - as far as *our* site, it's not a bug we'd fix...it's a configuration problem with Opera, so not really a bug we've done (or will do) anything about.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have `fit-to-width` option checked in Opera. Change/reset it and the problem goes away.